# Grunt less source maps change path prefix

Tags: gruntjs, less, source-maps, grunt-contrib-less

My config

```
server: {
    options: {
      sourceMap: true,
      sourceMapFilename: '.tmp/styles/main.css.map',
      sourceMapURL: '/styles/main.css.map'
    },
    files: {
      '.tmp/styles/main.css':
        'src/app/views/styles/application.less'
    }
  },
```

My structure

```
 .tmp
 src
 Gruntfile.js
```

so after calling grunt less:server

I am getting .tmp/styles/main.css.map
with attr "sources" everywhere src/ prefix
but I want without src/ because server starts from src/*

How can I change it ?

Answer (score 1):

Since version 1.0.0. grunt-contrib-less accepts the same options as the command line compiler does. You can get a list of these options by running `lessc` wihtout any argument on your command line:

```
  --source-map-rootpath=X  Adds this path onto the sourcemap filename and less file paths.
```

So you should use:

```
options: {
      sourceMap: true,
      sourceMapFilename: '.tmp/styles/main.css.map',
      sourceMapURL: '/styles/main.css.map',
      sourceMapRootpath: "/app/views/styles/"
    }
```

Comment: currently I have in my map '/app/views/styles/src/' how can I remove src ?